# Get value of an attribute

Tags: xpath

Here is my XML:-

```
<Book>
<BookKey>
<Value concept="TITLE" value="Inferno"/>
<Value concept="AUTHOR" value="Dan Brown"/>
</BookKey>
...etc...
</Book>
```

How can I get the book title value, i.e. "Inferno" with XPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
/Book/BookKey/Value/@value
```

To address the value attribute only when concept == `title` you might want:

```
/Book/BookKey/Value[@concept="Title"]/@value
```

Using `@` you can address attributes in XPath. Refer to this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)